# Adding additional meta data to django apps.py and accessing it from other apps

Tags: python-3.x, django, metadata, django-apps

I would like to add additional meta data to the apps.py which I can use the same way as "name" and "verbose_name". In particular this would allow me to create an app which displays information about other installed apps. The following approach does not seem to work:

App no1:

```
#apps.py / myapp
class MyappConfig(AppConfig):
name = "myapp"
verbose_name = "My app"
description = "whatever description i would like to add"
```

App no2:

```
#model.py / differentapp
apps.get_app_config("myapp").verbose_name # Works
apps.get_app_config("myapp").description # Fails
```

Is there a way to make this work? If not what would be a suitable approach to achive this goal?

Thank you for your help!

Comment: That's not how AppConfig work. You can't add custom variable into it. But you can use [app-conf](https://github.com/django-compressor/django-appconf) to achieve what you want to achieve.

Comment: Thank you for your answere that was what I assumed after reading the docs. Seems like the information needs to go into models.py as described for app-conf.

Comment: Oh I thought you can access the variable anywhere as long as your import the settings `from myapp.conf import settings`